# do i have to use instanof in this problem? or how should i code instead?

Tags: java

i wrote an example code for my question. i want to use polimorfism and i try to change a variable by the type of object. This code is working but is it the best way of that? Should i use a common method in both classes to return the variable? Thanks

```
package example;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}
class Bird extends Animal{}
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a;
        int leg=0;
        Scanner k=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=k.next();
        if(s.equals("dog")) a=new Dog();
        else a=new Bird();

        if(a instanceof Dog) leg+=4;
        else if(a instanceof Bird) leg+=2;
        System.out.println(leg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place common functionality into the parent class `Animal` and implement specific functionality into child classes `Bird` and `Dog`.

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract int legs();
}

class Bird extends Animal {
    @Override
    int legs() {
        return 2;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    int legs() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

There's no need for `instanceof`, just call the `legs` method of `Animal` and the implementing class will output the correct value.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();

        if(s.equals("dog")) { 
            animal = new Dog();
        } else {
            animal = new Bird();
        }

        System.out.println(animal.legs());
    }

}
```

Comment: ok you are right, i got it but why shouldn't I use instanceof and do it as yours? 
Does it work faster this way? Thanks a lot

Comment: No, because in this case, with `instanceof`, you completely bypass the benefits of polymorphism. Each class should know its own behaviour and properties. In your example, `Dog` and `Bird` are given their properties from outside, from the `main` method. That kinda defeats the purpose of having different child classes in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Put the common attributes and behaviors to the parent

```
abstract class Animal {
    public abstract int getLegs();
}

class Bird extends Animal {
    @Override
    public int getLegs() {
        return 2;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public int getLegs() {
         return 4;
    }
}
```

, Add a method that creates an object based on parameter this is `Factory Design pattern` [factory_pattern.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal animal;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String animalType = scanner.next();
    animal = getAnimal(animalType);
    if (animal != null)
        System.out.println(animal.getLegs());
    scanner.close();
}

static Animal getAnimal(String type) {
    if(type==null || "".equals(type)) return null;
    Animal animal;
    if ("dog".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
        animal = new Dog();
    } else if("bird".equalsIgnoreCase(type){
        animal = new Bird();
    }
    return animal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of legs the animal has should be contained within the subclass of Animal rather than set from the outside as you've currently got. Something like:

```
public abstract class Animal {
  protected int numLegs;

  public int getNumLegs() {
    return numLegs;
  }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
  public Dog() {
    numLegs = 4;
  }
}
```

Good luck!